# Python extracting specific substring

Tags: python, string, list, split

So I have the following String in Python:

```
teststr = "First Line.............................234" \
          "1.1.0 (L1) TestLine.........................567" \
          "1.1.1 (L1) Second Line.............................587"\
          "Third Line.............................856" \
          "1.1.2 (L2) Fourth Line.............................775"\
          "1.2.7 (L1) Fifth Line.............................262" \
          "1.5.3 (L1) Sixth Line .............................346"\
          "Seventh Line..............................234"
```

I need to save only the informations from (L1) in a List.

I can not iterate through lines with (if line contains L1 or something), because sometimes a (L1) information takes more than on line(Second Line Third Line for example).

I tried so much with splitting and joining the string again but nothing will work for me.

Has anyone any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Are there newlines between the lines? What is the expected output?

Comment: the expected output would be:

[Testline, Second LineThird Line, Fifth Line, Sixth LineSeventh Line] 

there are no newlines in between tho.

Comment: Please [**Edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69152990/edit) post with expected output and not in hard to read comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string on the regex and then loop over the data:

```
teststr = "First Line.............................234" \
          "1.1.0 (L1) TestLine.........................567" \
          "1.1.1 (L1) Second Line.............................587"\
          "Third Line.............................856" \
          "1.1.2 (L2) Fourth Line.............................775"\
          "1.2.7 (L1) Fifth Line.............................262" \
          "1.5.3 (L1) Sixth Line .............................346"\
          "Seventh Line..............................234"
import re
results = re.split(r'(\(L\d+\))',teststr)
```

This will split the input on any value that is similar to `(Ln)` where `n` can be any number.

Which gives a list with the following values:

```
['First Line.............................2341.1.0 ',
 '(L1)',
 ' TestLine.........................5671.1.1 ',
 '(L1)',
 ' Second Line.............................587Third Line.............................8561.1.2 ',
 '(L2)',
 ' Fourth Line.............................7751.2.7 ',
 '(L1)',
 ' Fifth Line.............................2621.5.3 ',
 '(L1)',
 ' Sixth Line .............................346Seventh Line..............................234']
```

We want to select only the values after `(L1)` in this case, so we loop (sliding) over the list and print the value only if it comes after `(L1)`.

```
for x, y in zip(results, results[1:]):
  if x == '(L1)':
    print(y)
```

The complete code becomes:

```
teststr = "First Line.............................234" \
          "1.1.0 (L1) TestLine.........................567" \
          "1.1.1 (L1) Second Line.............................587"\
          "Third Line.............................856" \
          "1.1.2 (L2) Fourth Line.............................775"\
          "1.2.7 (L1) Fifth Line.............................262" \
          "1.5.3 (L1) Sixth Line .............................346"\
          "Seventh Line..............................234"
import re
results = re.split(r'(\(L\d+\))',teststr)

for x, y in zip(results, results[1:]):
  if x == '(L1)':
    print(y)
```

Which gives:

```
 TestLine.........................5671.1.1 
 Second Line.............................587Third Line.............................8561.1.2 
 Fifth Line.............................2621.5.3 
 Sixth Line .............................346Seventh Line..............................234
```

Comment: That was very Helpful thank you! 
Can you (if you Want) explain how this works ?

Comment: @IRezzet added some explanations, let me know if there is still anything that is unclear.

Comment: thank you that was very helpful and easy to understand.
thanks also for the fast help!

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '(L1)'
for i in teststr.split('1.'):
    n = i.find(s)
    if n != -1:
        print(i[n+len(s):])
```

Output:

```
 TestLine.........................567
 Second Line.............................587Third Line.............................856
 Fifth Line.............................262
 Sixth Line .............................346Seventh Line..............................234
```

As you have shown in the comments under the question, if you want a list:

```
s = '(L1)'
lines = [i[n+len(s):]for i in teststr.split('1.') if (n := i.find(s)) != -1]
```